# JavaScript not randomly selecting names from the specific array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, random

I am making a random name picker (not a generator), and when I put Alex in the textbox it should pick a random name from `randomNicknames` array - which it works. But when I input a name other than Alex, it still picks a random names from `randomNicknames` array. I want to make it pick a name from `randomNicknames2` array when user inputs a name other than alex.

```js
let realName = document.getElementById("name");

let randomNicknames = [
    "Noob",
    "Doge",
    "Roblox Bully",
    "Mama",
    "Doodle"
];

let randomNicknames2 = [
    "Ironman",
    "Howard the Alien",
    "Roblox rich kid",
    "Moto Moto",
    "Muhammad the 2nd"
];

let randomNick = randomNicknames[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNicknames.length)];
let randomNick2 = randomNicknames2[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNicknames2.length)];

function generate() {
    if (realName == "Alex" || "alex" || "Alexander" || "alexander") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomNick;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomNick2;
    }
}
```

```css
p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Nickname Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
    Add your first name: <input type="text" id="name" autocomplete="off">
    <button onclick="generate()">Generate!</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    Your nickname: <p id="demo"></p> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `real name` variable will be having the `input` element and not the value of the input AFAIK and your if condition will always be truthy

Comment: `if (realName == "Alex" || "alex" || "Alexander" || "alexander")` that should be `if (realName == "Alex" || realName == "alex" || realName == "Alexander" || realName == "alexander")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was with the initialization of `realName` variable.

Add `.value` at the end:

```
let realName = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

Also put it inside the `generate()` function

```
function generate() {
        let realName = document.getElementById("name").value;
        if (realName === "Alex" || realName === "alex" || realName === "Alexander" || realName === "alexander") {

            let randomNick = randomNicknames[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNicknames.length)];
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomNick;

        } else {

            let randomNick2 = randomNicknames2[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNicknames2.length)];
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomNick2;

        }
        console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNicknames.length));
    }
```

You can also use a `console.log()` to check whether the variable holds the correct value

`console.log(realName);`

Comment: it always picks the same name

Comment: @JustanusualStuff Please see the updated answer.

*Add the nickname declaration inside the condition so that it always generates a new one when the function gets invoked.

Comment: nice, it works. btw why do you have to put `randomNick` inside the generate function instead of outside?

Comment: That's the reason it didn't change earlier when you click repeatedly. When you click the button the function gets invoked and then only the `randomNick` should replace its value based on the input. That happens only inside the condition. When it is outside the function, the value is always at its initial state so it can't be changed again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition to the below condition

```
if (realName == "Alex" || realName == "alex" || realName == "Alexander" ||realName ==  "alexander")
```

Use `.value` to get the value from the input box. Without it you will geth the whole input element

```js
let randomNicknames = [
    "Noob",
    "Doge",
    "Roblox Bully",
    "Mama",
    "Doodle"
];

let randomNicknames2 = [
    "Ironman",
    "Howard the Alien",
    "Roblox rich kid",
    "Moto Moto",
    "Muhammad the 2nd"
];

 

function generate() {
let realName = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (realName == "Alex" || realName == "alex" || realName == "Alexander" ||realName ==  "alexander") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomNicknames[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNicknames.length)];
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomNicknames2[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNicknames2.length)];
    }
}
```

```css
p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Nickname Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
    Add your first name: <input type="text" id="name" autocomplete="off">
    <button onclick="generate()">Generate!</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    Your nickname: <p id="demo"></p> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fails for `Alex`

Comment: why does putting `randomNicknames2[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNicknames2.length)];` separately not work?

Comment: It will work. I was just trying something. The advantage of my approach is that whenever the generate button is pressed a new random name will be assigned but in the OP's code it will be generated only once as it is generated outside the function

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to write

```
    if (realName.value == "Alex" || realName.value == "alex" || realName.value == "Alexander" || realName.value == "alexander") {
```

Which can be simplified to

```
    let name = realName.value.toLowerCase();
    if (name  == "alex" || name  == "alexander") {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let alexNames = [
    "Alex",
    "alex",
    "Alexander",
    "alexander"
];

let randomNicknames = [
    "Noob",
    "Doge",
    "Roblox Bully",
    "Mama",
    "Doodle"
];

let randomNicknames2 = [
    "Ironman",
    "Howard the Alien",
    "Roblox rich kid",
    "Moto Moto",
    "Muhammad the 2nd"
];

function generate() {
    let realName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    let randomNick = randomNicknames[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNicknames.length)];
    let randomNick2 = randomNicknames2[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNicknames2.length)];

   if (alexNames.includes(realName)) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomNick;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomNick2;
    }
}
```